# Switch Connected in Series

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary

I have encountered the following question on the net. I am trying to figure out how to approach the problem? Can someone help me with any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

There are switches that can be controlled by a remote, n such switches are connected in series and at the end of there is a bulb, the remote has a button that toggle the state of the switch (on to off and vice versa), but the remote only works in switches which have a electric connection to them, A switch is connected when all the previous switches are turned ON, and the bulb is on when all the switches are ON(assuming the first switch is always connected). At first all the switches are off and only the first switch is connected.

Input:

- N (number of switches ), 1 < N < 30
- K(number of times the button is pressed), 1 < k < 10^7

Output: 1 (if the bulb is on) , -1 (if it’s not)

Answer (score -1):

Lets denote the state of button as *0* (if the switch is OFF) and *1* (if the switch id OFF). So we have initial state as *0000...0* (n zeroes) and we have to reach the state *1111...1* (n ones) to let the bulb switch ON. Assume each state to be the corresponding binary number.

Let the 1st switch be the least significant bit and the nth bit be the most significant bit. When we toggle the switches at state *i*, then the next state will be *i+1*. This is easy to observe: if we write the *i-th* state in binary, let *j* be the position of the first *0* starting from least significant bit. After the toggle all the *1* before *j-th* position will become *0* and the bit at position *j* will become *1*, this will be the *(i+1)-th* state. This is equivalent to adding *1* to state *i*.

So to reach the final state, exactly *((2^(n+1)) - 1)* steps are required. So if k < number of steps required, then the bulb will be OFF, otherwise it will be ON.

Comment: Hm. Let there be two switches. What shall be the output for `K = 7` (2³-1), 8, 3 - and why?

Comment: @greybeard i did not get what you want to say

Comment: Two switches, the input and "toggle capability" of one (call it the 1st) connected to a power source, the output connected to input and "toggle capability" of the 2nd, output of the 2nd to the lamp (bulb? as in incandescent?), both switches initially off. On the first operation of the RC button, switch 1 turns "on". On the 2nd, it turns off again, simultaneously, switch 2 turn off - no power to, no light from the lamp. What happens when you operate the button for the 3rd time? The 4th, 7th (your formula), 8th time?

Comment: @greybeard 3rd time switch 1 turns on, and switch 2 remains on. Now switch 1 and 2 are connected to power. After 4th operation, 3rd switch turns on, 1st and 2nd switch turns off. Hope you can proceed further.